# Visual C# Express. Data can be save but until I close Visual C#

Tags: c#, saving-data

This Is the code for Adding the new Item...

```
    private KrystalCafeDatabaseEntities kce = new KrystalCafeDatabaseEntities();

    private Byte[] byteBLOBData;

    public AddItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cmbCategory.DataSource = kce.tblItemTypes;
        cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbCategory.ValueMember = "ItemType";

    }

    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fsBLOBFile = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byteBLOBData = new Byte[fsBLOBFile.Length];

            fsBLOBFile.Read(byteBLOBData, 0, byteBLOBData.Length);

            fsBLOBFile.Close();

            MemoryStream stmBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);

            pbImage.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tblItem Item = new tblItem();

        Item.Name = txtName.Text;

        Item.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

        Item.Image = byteBLOBData;

        Item.ItemType = (int)cmbCategory.SelectedValue;

        kce.AddTotblItems(Item);

        kce.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved! :D");

    }
}
```

}

The program runs normally but the data will only be stored for awhile, then If i either closed my program or edit my code the data I just added will be lost.

Comment: While the program is still running, are the changes persisted to the database?

Comment: Can we have the source of KrystalCafeDatabaseEntities ? Otherwise it's impossible to tell...

Answer (score 0):

One likely error is that `KrystalCafeDatabaseEntities` opens a transaction and you need to commit that transaction after calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Isn't `SaveChanges()` normally commiting the transaction in Entity Framework?